Status of charset UTF8 / utf8mb4 in MySQL 8.0 and PHP 8.1?
My question is what is now the best way to specify the character set UTF-8 (the real, four-byte UTF-8) in MySQL 8.0 and PHP 8.1, and whether the examples below are specifying the real, four-byte UTF-8, or the three-byte subset of it?
I know that there are many, many posts about this question, however most of them are old. I am aware that in the bad old days there was a MySQL character set called "utf8" that was a three-byte subset of the real UTF-8, and that to get true, four-byte UTF-8 you had to specify the character set "utf8mb4". However, I was under the impression that newer versions of MySQL and PHP were now using true UTF-8.
My php.ini file (located at /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini) contains these lines:
; PHP's default character set is set to UTF-8.
; https://php.net/default-charset
default_charset = "UTF-8"

I have been reading this tutorial:
https://www.phptutorial.net/php-pdo/pdo-connecting-to-mysql/
In its discussion of how to make a PDO connection to the MySQL database server it says to use the following data source name format:
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bookdb;charset=UTF8";

There is no mention in the php.ini file or in the tutorial about whether this UTF-8/UTF8 is the true, four-byte UTF-8 or the old one.
Can anyone shed any light on this?

What's wrong with simply using utf8mb4 though? And what could be possible logic behind dismissing curated Stack Overflow answers but for some reason blindly trusting some old lame PDO tutorial

@BillKarwin NOWHERE that answer is from "2008". It has been updated 2 MONTHS AGO. THIS is how this blessed site works. It has its reference answers updated.

@BillKarwin I need to agree with Your Common Sense on this one: this question is covered by a regularly updated duplicate. Your answer should be deleted from here and added there, so all great quality answers are in one place.

That tutorial you linked to is really bad. It was already bad when it was written. Just take a look at this line if ($pdo) {. This is pure nonsense.

It's not entirely clear what you are asking about as your question is mixing PHP and MySQL together. Note that the PHP character set you specify in default_charset has no relation to the character set you specify in your PDO connection.

If you are asking for the status of whether the deprecated character set has been removed, you can easily check this on the latest MySQL 9 and see if it works. But I doubt it's what you are asking about.

FYI neither MySQL 8 nor PHP 8.1 are considered recent. PHP 8.1 is an outdated PHP version and you should consider an upgrade.

The linked duplicate question should explain everything you need to know. As YCS pointed out it's been kept up to date. First, you need to understand the difference between PHP and MySQL. The settings in php.ini will never mention 3-byte UTF-8 because that thing never existed in PHP. It has been solely the problem of MySQL.

"utf8 is expected in a future release to become an alias for utf8mb4." (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/charset-unicode-sets.html).  That is, you must spell out "utf8mb4" until some version later than 8.4.  [I predict that changing the alias will cause chaos, but that is another matter.]
